# JavaFX Property's invalidate() method not called with binding

Tags: javafx, properties, binding, custom-controls, invalidation

I'm trying to make a custom control in JavaFX using some binding feature. This is my problem: I have a class with a `DoubleProperty` that I use to calculate the position of an element inside my custom control. Here is the code:

```
public class CustomControl extends Region {
  private DoubleProperty positionProperty;

  public CustomControl() {
    positionProperty= new DoublePropertyBase(0.0) {
      @Override public Object getBean() { return CustomControl.this; }
      @Override public String getName() { return "position"; }
      @Override protected void invalidated() { updatePostion(); }
    };
  }

  public DoubleProperty positionProperty() { return positionProperty; }
  public double getPosition() { return positionProperty.get(); }
  public void setPosition(double value) { positionProperty.set(value); }

  private void updatePosition() {
    double value = doubleProperty.get();
    //compute the new position using value
  }
}
```

In my application i have two `CustomControl`s and i want that when i call the method `setPosition()` on the first of them, the second one updates the position of its component as well. To do so I binded the `positionProperty` of the two `CustomControl`s like this:

```
CustomControl control1 = new CustomControl();
CustomControl control2 = new CustomControl();
control2.positionProperty.bind(control1.positionProperty);
```

Then when I call for example

```
control1.setPosition(50.0);
```

only the position of the component of `control1` is updated, indeed when i call the method `setPosition()`, the method `invalidated()` of the `positionProperty` of `control1` is actually called, but not the one of the `positionProperty` of `contol2` as I espected. How shoul i achieve what i want? Thank you!

**PS**: I also noticed that using the method `bindBidirectional()` instead of `bind()` works, but shouldn't it work using only `bind()` too?

**EDIT**: example code is available here: https://luca_bertolini@bitbucket.org/luca_bertolini/customcontrolexample.git

Comment: Any reason you are creating an anonymous-class implementation of `DoubleProperty`? Your problem probably stems from your overriding the `invalidated` method, without calling the base (`super`) method.

Comment: @sillyfly I created an anonymous class because i'll need to have lots of these `CustomControl`s on the screen and using an anonymous class instead of setting a listener on the property will provide less memory usage and less computing complexity. Also the default implementation of `invalidate()` is empty so it doesn't change much if i call `super.invalidate()` or not.

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. I tested this and it worked exactly as expected (`System.out.println(control2.getPosition());` displayed `50.0`). There must be an error somewhere else in code you haven't posted.

Comment: I added an example project that reproduces the problem... Am i doing it wrong or the only way to achieve what i want is to use listeners on the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaFX uses lazy evaluation for all bindings, which means that when a change occurs on your `out.positionProperty` object, the new value is not immediately taken into account. This happens later, if and only when the value is subsequently requested.

Try this:

```
out.positionProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
    @Override
    public void invalidated(final Observable observable) {
       // System.out.println("It must go now.");
    }
});
```

and you will see that this time your code works as you want.

Comment: Yes, it works. I guess it's the only way to achieve what i want . Thank you!